# text box for quantity update using refresh icon in ionic2 and angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, ionic2

Actually I want a text box like this [image: when I give some value like 20 ,using that refresh button i will update my value]
, like this website http://www.wholesalebox.in/cart

My html is like this :

```
<ion-col width-25>

    <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" size="1" class="form-control qty_box"><span class="input-group-btn">
    <button clear type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-primary" data-original-title="Update"><ion-icon name="refresh"></ion-icon>

    </button>
    </span>

</ion-col>
```

Comment: i tried only ionic portion what code i sent

Comment: can any one help how to do this using ionic2